# Microstrategy Web API - JAVA SDK

Tags: java, microstrategy

I am developing something with Microstrategy JAVA SDK. But I am not getting the com.microstrategy.webapi.serverinfo class. Can any one tell me which .jar file I am missing

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the `serverinfo` class in the JavaWebAPI.jar, in the WAR file in the `Mobile Server JSP` folder in your MicroStrategy installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all jar files placed in your installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MicroStrategy). Usually i add JavaWebAPI.jar and Web*.jar.

Comment: Thanks Maverick. Can I get the JavaWebAPI.jar from Microstrategy site?

Comment: I have only downloaded MSDL and WAR files.. the jar files comes with the installation